# What's the domain of usability of these two expressions for entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

$$dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$$

$$S=k\ln \Omega$$

What assumptions are being made about the system/process that allow for using those expressions?

Comment: In your  first formula, you cannot use a derivative $dQ$, but a variation $\delta Q$. And this is only true for a reversible process, that is $dS  = \frac{\delta Q_{Reversible}}{T}$. Second formula is correct.

Comment: I'm interested in the precise ramifications - for example I've read something about the second formula being a result of equal probabilities for all microstates, else it is replaced by Gibbs entropy. I have a feeling that the second one, being sort of 'thermodynamic' (and so, inherently "macroscopic") has an even tighter region of usability.

Comment: Not at all, this is a fundamental formula, which states that the entropy is proportionnal to the logarithm of the number of configurations. See the grave of [Boltzmann](http://www.google.fr/imgres?sa=X&biw=1280&bih=872&tbm=isch&tbnid=gtlXe8Me9UHi_M:&imgrefurl=http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/images/boltzmann/boltzmann-tomb-8.html&docid=XqZ_2krbpt3MeM&imgurl=http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/images/boltzmann/P7140526.JPG&w=2560&h=1920&ei=pW-3UaqEPNDY0QX5oICoCQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=4&vpy=222&dur=1917&hovh=194&hovw=259&tx=59&ty=215&page=1&tbnh=147&tbnw=193&start=0&ndsp=36&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:84)

Comment: Each microscopic configuration is equiprobable, the entropy itself is a macroscopic quantity

Comment: Then I don't understand what is meant here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_entropy_formula#Generalization (admittedly its a wikipedia article so I know it should be taken with a grain of salt, but still something's got to give?)

Comment: Yes, you are right, the statistical entropy $S= - \Sigma p_i log p_i$ is a more general formula, and you go back to the original Boltzmann formula if the probabilities are equal, that is $P_i = \frac{1}{\Omega}$. Sorry.